# gaierror when trying to send mail via SMTP

Tags: python, docker, smtplib

I am sending mails via Python towards our customers, recently however I get some error message in our production environment:

```
intranet-worker     | mksp-worker  2021-07-30 07:49:39,693 INFO  mails.py:setup_mailserver Logging in to mail server "smtp.strato.de"
intranet-worker     | 07:49:39:   0.01s ! d8730ffa0ce644de9d5595cbe13290c8:send_welcome_mail failed, gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
intranet-worker     | Traceback (most recent call last):
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arq/worker.py", line 525, in run_job
intranet-worker     |     result = await task
intranet-worker     |   File "/app/tasks/mails.py", line 106, in send_welcome_mail
intranet-worker     |     return await send_mail_to(user.email, tpl, values)
intranet-worker     |   File "/app/tasks/mails.py", line 50, in send_mail_to
intranet-worker     |     mail_server = await setup_mailserver()
intranet-worker     |   File "/app/tasks/mails.py", line 20, in setup_mailserver
intranet-worker     |     mail_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(settings.smtp_server, settings.smtp_port)
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1034, in __init__
intranet-worker     |     SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
intranet-worker     |     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
intranet-worker     |     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1040, in _get_socket
intranet-worker     |     new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
intranet-worker     |     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
intranet-worker     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
intranet-worker     |     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
intranet-worker     | socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The code is as simple as this:

```
async def setup_mailserver():
    log.info('Logging in to mail server %s' % settings.smtp_server)
    log.debug('Going to use username %s for authentication' % settings.smtp_username)
    try:
        mail_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(settings.smtp_server, settings.smtp_port)
        mail_server.login(settings.smtp_username, settings.smtp_password)
        return mail_server
```

The value `settings.smtp_server` is `smtp.strato.de` as evidenced by the logging output directly above the error message. The fun part is: running it locally, it works fine. Running it in our dev and stage cluster, it works perfectly fine. This error only occurs in our production environment. The main difference is that both dev and staging run on Azure Kubernetes, while prod runs on a normal Linux server with docker-compose. It uses the same exact image though.

When I get myself a bash within the container, I can happily resolve and ping `smtp.strato.de`:

```
[user@hostname docker]$ docker-compose exec intranet-worker bash
root@cef64049ef54:/app# ping smtp.strato.de
PING smtp.strato.de (81.169.145.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from smtp.strato.de (81.169.145.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=20.1 ms
64 bytes from smtp.strato.de (81.169.145.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=20.2 ms
^C
--- smtp.strato.de ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 3ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.113/20.169/20.226/0.152 ms
```

From the same application in then same container I’m also doing requests to external APIs which are also DNS resolved, they work fine. Im quite lost what could cause this error and I'd appreciate any support. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a small hint in this log line:

```
intranet-worker     | mksp-worker  2021-07-30 07:49:39,693 INFO  mails.py:setup_mailserver Logging in to mail server "smtp.strato.de"
```

Note specifically the `"smtp.strato.de"`, it contains the quotation marks. I essentially had quotation marks around the SMTP values in the `docker-compose.yml` file as below:

```
    - SMTP_SERVER="smtp.strato.de"
```

Removing the quotation marks made the code work as expected.